# split contents of a column in a python pandas Dataframe and create a new Dataframe with the newly separated list of strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I have my
[my original pandas dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKijk.png) as such, where the 'comment' column consist of unseparated lists of strings and another column called 'direction' indicating whether the overall content in 'comment' column suggests positive or negative comments, where 1 represents positive comments and 0 represents negative comments.

Now I wish to create a new Dataframe by separating all the strings under 'comment' by delimiter '' and assign the each new list of strings as a seperate row with their original 'direction' respectively. So it would looks something like this [new dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVRSY.png).

I wonder how should I achieve so?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
df.comments = df.comments.str.split('<END>')
df = df.explode('comment')
```